# need to inject the output of a javascript into a php script; is this possible?

Tags: php, javascript

both codes can be also seen side by side at panelbackup(dot)com/codes

ok, so I have this code located on page 1.html which appends 4 random numbers after the given url :

```
<head><script>window.onload = function() {
        var links = document.links;
        for(var h in links) {
                var rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10000);
                links[h].href += (links[h].href.indexOf('') == -1 ? '?' : '')+''+rand;
        }
}
</script>
</head>


<a href="http://panelbackup.com/blahblah">randomURL</a>
```

and I then need to inject or call this into the following php script:

```
<?php
$a=fopen('http://output from javascript','r');
$b = stream_get_contents($a);
echo $b;
fclose($a);
```

any ideas on how this could be accomplished? the php script is on 1.php and the javascript is on 1.html located at panelbackup(dot)com

Comment: Do you know how that data is going to get to your server? Are they submitting a form? Are you using AJAX to send it asynchronously?

Comment: Since you're just using random numbers, why not create them in PHP with `rand()` and then echo the numbers into your script tag for JavaScript to use?

Comment: I'd like to use fopen and get_contents in php in order to load the content automatically, but I'm just having issues trying to use straight php, as if I attempt to use print rand(0, 9) within the fopen call after the hard url,$a=fopen('http://output from javascript','r'); it is not parsing the way I'd like. Any ideas on using solely php on this one?

Comment: You're trying to add to the query string of an anchor tag, so presumably the random data is intended be part of the request when the user clicks the link. Why then aren't you treating it as a standard request parameter on the PHP side?

Comment: this will not be activated by a user click. I am trying to set it up where each time the page is loaded, a url with the random numbers appended is loaded. Each refresh, the url with a new set of numbers, and so on. Ex: domain.com/page632 then domain.com/page593 etc etc on each refresh

Comment: So you're talking about the URL displayed in the browser's address bar for your page, not the URL that is in an href of an anchor tag? If so, and given your comments under my answer, I'd suggest a major rewrite of your question to say what you really want.

Answer (score 0):

In your JavaScript why don't you set the random number as a named parameter and then access it from PHP the same as any other request parameter?

```
links[h].href += (links[h].href.indexOf('?') == -1 ? '?' : '&')+'newParam='+rand;
```

This will change the link to be

```
<a href="http://panelbackup.com/blahblah?newParam=153">
or
<a href="http://panelbackup.com/blahblah?existingParam=whatever&newParam=153">
(assuming the random number is 153)
```

Note: your code was testing for a '?' in the existing url and adding one if not found, but you need to add an ampersand if '?' was found or your random number will end up concatenated to the end of the existing parameter's value.

EDIT: PhpMyCoder's suggestion to generate the random numbers on the PHP side is a better way to go.

Comment: yes, I want it appended directly. What I am wanting is each time the page is loaded, it loads the url with the random numbers appended to the end. If you refresh, the url with a different set of random numbers is loaded, and so on and so forth. Any ideas on a good code for that? I may be overthinking this whole thing..

Comment: we can actually forget about the javascript, as I was just using that in an attempt to generate the random url outside of php and then have it called, as like I said, I am having issues generating it from within that php code I provided, and then loading it, however it would much cleaner if I could do this solely with php.

Comment: @Daniel - Regarding your first comment, your code as posted tests whether the href already has a ? in it, which implies you're not sure whether there might be some existing query-string parameters in some cases _before_ you add your random number. If you add the random to the end of an existing parameter it will break whatever that parameter is for so you need to add an ampersand first.

Comment: yes the code I was initially using for this script did have the ? in it. I must not have removed that. My php is a bit rusty, how should I get it cleaned up, and possibly working as I am describing? I appreciate all the help guys.